# how to prevent bash from returning wildcard when variable is in double quotes?

Tags: bash, for-loop, wildcard, glob

Here the second variable is not a found directory but a search pattern. How to prevent this behavior ?

```
mkdir -p mytestdir001
for f in "mytestdir???"; do
  echo $f
  echo "$f"
done
```

result:

```
mytestdir001
mytestdir???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misinterpreted the problem. The issue is that you have quoted the *wildcards* when you shouldn't have.

```
mkdir -p mytestdir001
for f in "mytestdir"???; do
  echo $f
  echo "$f"
done
```